# Nodemailer not working in heroku

Tags: javascript, html, npm

I was curious if anyone has ran into a problem I am currently having.  I work from cloud9 and have nodemailer running perfectly fine, all emails have been sent from a form I made.  I made a small server and deployed to heroku where nothing has been changed in the code but an environmental variable (so no one sees my password) and the email does not send.  Been researching for hours and was curious if anyone knew anymore about the matter?  I know gmail doesn’t like weird apps accessing accounts which I have adjusted in my settings.  But thinking maybe the problem lies in heroku? Any insight on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am currently away from my computer will post code when I am by it, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue this morning and it took me a while to figure it out. Apparently the issue was not with Heroku or NodeMailer but with the gmail account I was using.
I good suggestion would be to log your errors which will give you a better idea of whats wrong.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
  url: url + 'mail',
  data: JSON.stringify(req),
  contentType : "application/json",
  success: function(data){
    console.log("Network success " + data);
  },
  error: function(e,status,msg){
        console.log("Network error." + msg)
  }
});
```

you will also want to log your nodemailer responses. something like this.

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){

  console.log("error : " + JSON.stringify(error));
  console.log("info : " + JSON.stringify(info))

});
```

[image]

After logging I realized that gmail was asking me to login into my browser again for some kind of  security check.
After I cleared the check I was able to send mails from my Node.js app.

Comment: It was a pain! I am glad you got it working.  I was tinkering with the settings for awhile on the gmail accounts.  But my problem lied in the environmental variables I defined on heroku....  I had a brain fart and was using process.env.email/password on heroku which is only needed in my local server I am using.

Comment: This can be temporally resolved by: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha